# How do I set the signingkey from a jwk to verify a jwt with jjwt

Tags: java, jwt, jwk, jjwt

To verify and parse the jwt token the code is

```
public static Claims decodeJWT(String jwt) {
    //This line will throw an exception if it is not a signed JWS (as expected)
    Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
        .setSigningKey(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(SECRET_KEY))
        .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
    return claims;
}
```

My jwk looks like

```
public class MyJwkDto {
    String kty;
    String crv;
    String kid;
    String x;
    String y;
}
```

as exaple

```
  {
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "kid": "UD9Jr8TKPk3MI_RQg2LX3UFwaV4U3nhIzUO_pU78q4M",
    "x": "lKgBPjCtzRiYOC1Oyi_3qi6Ux7Wcxaem35nx9IgEqRY",
    "y": "fNghfAOzpsSudHo6tq1JB3FdKkdQnH_tLj2tajc8ZUM"
  }
```

But what do I use now for the `SECRET_KEY`?

Comment: x and y are the parameters for the public ES256 key. The linked Q/A shows how to use them to generate a public key object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Elliptic Curve ASCII-Armor keys in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213317/printing-elliptic-curve-ascii-armor-keys-in-java)

Comment: Ok thanks Ill give it a try. I hoped there are som libs doing this for me :( but thanks for the answer

Comment: I think with https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/src/master/ you can directly deal with keys in JWK format.

Comment: Thanks @jps this is exactly what im looking for

Comment: You should consider writing your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I will. After i finished my work

Answer (score 0):

So what i did is:

First changed the lib from jjwt to nimbus-jose-jwt. After that I stored the jwks as .a JWKSet

```
public JWKSet getJwks(String token) {
    try {
        SignedJWT signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);
        JWTClaimsSet payload = signedJWT.getJWTClaimsSet();
        return JWKSet.parse(payload.getJSONObjectClaim("jwks"));
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

After that the validation of a jwk worked as follows

```
public boolean verifyToken(String token, JWKSet jwkSet) {
    try {
        SignedJWT signedJWT = SignedJWT.parse(token);
        JWSHeader header = signedJWT.getHeader();
        String kid = header.toJSONObject().get("kid").toString();
        JWK jwk = jwkSet.getKeyByKeyId(kid);
        final ECKey ecPublicJWK = new ECKey.Builder(jwk.toECKey()).build();
        JWSVerifier verifier = new ECDSAVerifier(ecPublicJWK);
        return signedJWT.verify(verifier);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (JOSEException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Thanks to @jps